# Connecting Customer's Domain to my Domain in Plesk

Tags: vps, plesk

I run a VPS with plesk on it. I will like to connect my clients domain (external) to a subdomain created for the client in my plesk setup. Below is the scenario.

I have a domain in plesk, say **[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)**, for each client I setup a subdomain where I host the application say **client1.mydomain.com**, and **client2.mydomain.com**.

Now I want my client to enjoy my application through their own domain e.g **[www.client1.com](http://www.client1.com)**, now **[www.client1.com](http://www.client1.com)** is to be pointed to **client1.mydomain.com**, and **[www.client2.com](http://www.client2.com)** to point to **client2.mydomain.com**.

I have added an **A** record for **client1.com** with my server IP but it points to my top domain **[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)** and NOT the subdomain **client1.mydomain.com** which I want.

What do I need to change to have the below:

**client1.com** => **client1.mydomain.com**

**client2.com** => **client2.mydomain.com**

I don't want the redirection or domain masking. I want it like the way we have it in **blogger.com** or **wordpress.com**

Comment: Did you try .htaccess file?

Comment: No i did not.... what do i need to do with this, if you dont mind guiding me.